# Getting the current MediaTypeFormatter from the Request object, possible?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to get the MediaTypeFormatter from the request object, is this possible ?

So if the request came in as a

```
    application/json
```

then I would like to get the MediaTypeFormatter which should be, in this case, a JsonMediaTypeFormatter.

The reason I need to do this is so that my api methods can support both MediaTypeFormatters (i.e. XML and JSON).

I am returning a HttpResponseMessage and settting the Content to ObjectContent and i am required to pass in the media type formatter, if i hard code this value to json then it isn't going to support xml.

Anyone done something like this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Web API framework automatically handles selecting the correct MediaTypeFormatter based on the `Accept` header sent in the request.  You should not need to be concerned with setting the response content type in your API methods unless you're doing something special.  Let the framework handle it; that is what it is designed for.  See @Badri's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `Request.CreateResponse` method. Do not try to find out the formatter based on media type. ASP.NET Web API does content negotiation for you. What if the request comes with quality factor and stuff? It will get complicated to write all that logic and it is already done in the framework code. All you got to do is to use the method like this - `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, product);` and return the response object instead of setting `ObjectContent` yourself. Depending on the formatter chosen from conneg, your object will get serialized. Or, do you have a specific scenario where you cannot use this?

Comment: So let's say I have a controller action with a return type of HttpResponseMessage. Inside the controller action I use an instance of an interface with a method signature of "object GetStuff()" to store a value in "object stuff". My instance has "public object GetStuff() { return new List<string>(); }". If I then call Request.CreateResponse(stuff), the response blows up with "application/xml" because the XML serializer can't deal with a typeof(object). If I instead though said "var content = ObjectContent(foo.GetType(), foo, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()) then it works just fine. Suggestions?

Comment: I'll reply to my own comment - I ended up writing additional "HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(this HttpRequestMessage request)" extension methods. I removed the generic <T> from the method signature, and took a parameter of "object value" rather than "T value." If I toss in anything but strictly an object it will go to the framework's methods. If it hits one of my extension methods then I check if the value is null. If not, I create a new ObjectContent() instance with value.GetType(). If it's null that I just set the content to be null.